# Cat selected files fast and easy?

Tags: file, merge, terminal, cat

I have been cat'ing files in the Terminal untill now.. but that is time consuming when done alot. What I want is something like:

I have a folder with hundreds of files, and I want to effectively cat a few files together.
For example, is there a way to select (in the Finder) five split files;

`file.txt.001`, `file.txt.002`, `file.txt.003`, `file.txt.004`

.. and then right click on them in the Finder, and just click Merge?

I know that isn't possible out of the box of course, but with an Automator action, droplet or shell script, is something like that possible to do? Or maybe assigning that cat-action a keyboard shortcut, and when hit selected files in the Finder, will be automatically merged together to a new file AND placed in the same folder, WITH a name based on the original split files?

In this example file.001 through file.004 would magically appear in the same folder, as a file named fileMerged.txt ?

I have like a million of these kind of split files, so an efficient workflow for this would be a life saver. I'm working on an interactive book, and the publisher gave me this task..

Comment: Does it have to have GUI (it sounds like you want to select files by clicking on them)? If not you could write simple shell script to do that.

Comment: No, doesn't have to be in a GUI.. but I'm not that good with scripts, neither Applescripts nor bash sctips.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat * > output.file
```

works as a sh script.  It's piping the contents of the files into that `output.file`.
`*` expands to all files in the directory.

Comment: But all my files aren't in different directories.. I have one folder with thousands of files:

speech1.txt.001
speech1.txt.002
speech1.txt.003
sound1.mp3.001
sound1.mp3.002
sound1.mp3.003
trollspeak1.avi.001
trollspeak1.avi.002
trollspeak1.avi.003
trollspeak1.avi.004
page120-150.txt.001
page120-150.txt.002
page120-150.txt.003


If there's a way to just select the files belonging together and hitting a shortcut that merges them automatically AND names the output file based on the input files.. Or right click, or drag them onto a droplet.. just something faster than using the terminal..

:-)

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your description of the file names you can automate that very easily with bash. e.g.

```sh
PREFIXES=`ls -1 | grep -o "^.*\." | uniq`
for PREFIX in $PREFIXES; do cat ${PREFIX}* > ${PREFIX}.all; done
```

This will merge all files in one directory that share the same prefix.

`ls -1` lists all files in a directory (if it spans multiple directories can use `find` instead. `grep -o "^.*\."` will match everything up to the last dot in the file name (you could also use `sed -e 's/.[0-9]*$/./'` to remove the last digits. uniq will filter all duplicates. Then you have something like `speech1.txt. sound1.txt.` in the `PREFIXES` variable. The next line loops through those and merges the groups of files individually using the * wildcard.

Comment: By making a bash script? How would that script know which folder is currently viewed in Finder? But if I'm understanding what ur saying correctly, it's possible to have a Finder window open with thousands of split files, run a bash script simply by typing (for example) mergescript in the terminal, and voila.. all files in directory merged?? THAT would... hahaha.. Make my life a living dream!!! :)

Comment: I am not using the finder, but I assume you could run that script from the finder (and the script would use the finder directory as its working directory). But you can also do that from the terminal - which is helpful to see if anything goes wrong (cd /your/directory and then go ahed with the magic ;) )